# Why doesn't this requestAnimationFrame debounce example work?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, dom-events, requestanimationframe, debouncing

If you open the console and scroll this example up and down, you see `no debounce` followed by `debounced` many times. Instead it should act as a debounce function, so you should see multiple `no debounce` for every one `debounced`.

That's also what it says in https://gomakethings.com/debouncing-your-javascript-events/ where the example comes from. So it works for him but I can't get it to work. How can I make it work like that?

`requestAnimationFrame` and `cancelAnimationFrame` is supported in all major browsers so it must be something wrong in the way I'm using the code.

```js
// Setup a timer
var timeout;

// Listen for resize events
window.addEventListener('scroll', function ( event ) {

 console.log( 'no debounce' );

 // If there's a timer, cancel it
 if (timeout) {
  window.cancelAnimationFrame(timeout);
 }

 // Setup the new requestAnimationFrame()
 timeout = window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {

  // Run our scroll functions
  console.log( 'debounced' );

 });

}, false);
```

```html
Hi, there! Start scrolling.<br><br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
The end.
```

Comment: It [seems to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCVu3.png) in the way you describe you want it to for me?

Comment: That's how it works for me. Like I said in my post `you should see multiple no debounce for every one debounced` rather than 1 for 1.

Comment: Ah, I focussed on this bit of your post: _"you see no debounce followed by debounced many times"_, which doesn't appear to be happening either.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're saying now - you mean you see the pair of them many times, not that you see debounced many times after seeing no debounce once. Much confusion at this end :)

Comment: FWIW, the demo on the page you linked to appears to behave the same for me also - I see one of each logged constantly.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: The snippet behaves as described on Safari 12. The original article explicitly states this:

> > [...]Firefox fires the event slow and sensibly, IE and Webkit go totally spastic.
>
> Chrome has since fixed this issue, behaving more like Firefox. But Safari (at least version 12, the one on my machine) still fires an insane number of events.

And sure enough, tried in Safari and got debounced events:
[image: Screenshots of debounced events in Safari].

My original answer stands except that I have reduced my equivocation.

**Original**

The snippet is a non-conventional debounce, designed to prevent multiple scroll events on the same frame. The behavior of the snippet is bound to the browser you're using. I also imagine it's worse for iOS, but haven't bothered trying on a device (mostly because I can't run snippets from my device...).

If you look at [Debounce in JavaScript — Improve Your Application’s Performance](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-in-javascript-improve-your-applications-performance-5b01855e086) you'll see that while their debounce code is very similar it includes a delay (`wait`). This is a traditional debounce method.

```
// Credit David Walsh (https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)

// Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
// be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
// N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
// leading edge, instead of the trailing.
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;

  return function executedFunction() {
    var context = this;
    var args = arguments;

    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };

    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;

    clearTimeout(timeout);

    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);

    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};
```

The original snippet in the question defends against `'scroll'` being fired more than once per frame, in which case, a requestAnimationFrame is canceled and the event is effectively debounced.